# C# Regular Expression Nested Paraenthisis Recursive

Tags: c#, regex, recursion, nested

Need help to find the regular expression.

```
Text = @"{'the quick' | 'the lazy'}{{{'BEFORE'} 'fox' } | {{'BEFORE'} 'lion'}}"
```

Result String Array Should be -

```
[0] = 'the quick' | 'the lazy',
[1] = BEFORE/1 fox | BEFORE/2 lion
```

Unless two or more strings are split by |, I need them to side by side.

Comment: This is no Regex-Service, you have to show some effort yourself. You arent asking for help here but for some one who does your homework.

Comment: Do it in C#... It is perhaps doable in regex but it would be hell.

Comment: thanks for the comment  xanatos, I am new to C# and trying to create a recursive function to divide them by {|}. any reference will be helpful.

Comment: @ImranMohamad You don't need a recursive method. You don't recurse anything. You need a state machine.

Comment: @ImranMohamad There are around 4 possible states, all with 1 or 2 possible exit transitions... states: 1. Before top level `{`, 2. after top level `{`, 3. after opening `'`, 4. after closing `'`, 1. after closing top level `}` (this is the same state as Before top level `{`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help. After thinking a bit, I was able to find the simple solution.

```
string sampleText = "{'what is' | 'when is'}{BEFORE/2 }{doing | 'to do'}{ NEAR/3 }{'to ensure our' | 'to ensure that' | 'to make sure our' | 'to make sure that our' | 'so our' | 'so that our'}{ BEFORE/4 }{doesn*t | 'does not' | 'will not' | won*t}";
            List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
            Match mt = Regex.Match(sampleText, @"\}([^{]*)\{");
            string value = sampleText.Replace(mt.Value, "},{");
            string[] newArray = value.Split(",".ToCharArray());
            foreach (string st in newArray)
            {
                list.Add(new List<string>(st.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split('|')));
            }
```